How to ensure consistent sorting of query results with Elasticsearch 8?
I need an Elasticsearch cluster to sort results consistently. My initial solution was something like this:
"sort": [
    {"timestamp": {"order": "asc"}}, 
    {"_id": {"order": "asc"}}
]

However, I've learned that _id for sorting is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
What alternatives do I have to ensure consistent sort order?
Elasticsearch does give me this cryptic warning:
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py:200: ElasticsearchWarning: Loading the fielddata on the _id field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. If you require sorting or aggregating on this field you should also include the id in the body of your documents, and map this field as a keyword field that has [doc_values] enabled

But I'm new to elasticsearch and have no idea how I'd go about doing this, or how to add this to existing indices.

You can add id field to you index, and copy _id to id, see link
